# log4net change LogLevel in web.config form test code

Tags: c#, web-config, log4net

Here is log4net config section from my service `web.config`:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="OutputDebugStringAppender">
    ...
  </appender>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender">
    ...
  </appender>
  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
    ...
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="OutputDebugStringAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I would like to change `<level value="INFO"/>` to `<level value="DEBUG"/>` during functional test (C#) preparation by hooking to existing `web.config` file.

**---EDIT---**

To make thing clear. This is not unit test. This is E2E test working on production service artifacts deployed to test-env. The only thing I can do is to modify `web.config` file.

**!---EDIT---**

Currently, I have two ideas:

1) Parse `web.config` as XML file,

2) Use regex (I know that I'll have two problems then :) )

I wonder if there is a universal way to change log level (maybe some kind of log4net configuration API for C#?)

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Log4net: How to enable debug logging at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176935/log4net-how-to-enable-debug-logging-at-runtime)

Comment: @Fildor Yes, I saw that before but this solution requires changes in service code. I would like to manage this form test code without changes in production code.

Comment: Why do you think this would need to change production code? When and where do you run those tests?

Comment: @Fildor @Peter End2End test code is another project, it takes built service binaries and deploys them to test environment.  In next step test triggers client app which communicates with service and in cleanup logs form service are collected. In my opinion GetRepository() method should be pointed somehow to service `web.config` to establish proper context.

Comment: So, we're **not** talking about Tests as in "UnitTests executed in a Framework like NUnit" is that correct? It's just production artifacts on a test-evironment , right?

Comment: @Fildor That's correct. I'm sorry, My problem explanation must be misleading.

Comment: Just a little bit. I was initially assuming we are talking about Tests in a TestSuite, which would make it easy: use the dupe to adjust LogLevel programmatically on Test-Prep ... What possibilities do you have to intervene? Can you manipulate certain files before they are deloyed?

Comment: @Fildor The deployment procedure is quite immovable and it is the last thing that I would like to modify. But tests are running form user context with full access to deployment dir and  i can do a lot of things after deployment, including: modifying config files and restarting application pool (service is under IIS).

It is worth to say that I've managed to do this temporarily by modifying XML with regex after deployment. I would like to implement better solution now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best solutions.
I've abandoned searching for log4net mechanisms and regex solutions.
The final version is:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(configFilePath);
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//log4net/root/level");
node.Attributes["value"].Value = "DEBUG";
doc.Save(configFilePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to edit your config files. You can change to loglevel at runtime with in you test classes:

```
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).Root.Level = Level.Debug;
((log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository()).RaiseConfigurationChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Please see marked dupe. Exact same answer. (By yourself, btw, haha )